# Mixing yaml and json

Tags: yaml

Yaml is a superset of json meaning I can literally just slap json into a .yml file and it works.

I would like to mostly write json, but for my code blocks it would be great to switch to the yaml literal style.

Chat Gpt Said I can do this, (but it's wrong though the idea seems valid to me)

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "description": |
        This is a multi-line
        description using the YAML
        literal style in a JSON file.
    "age": 30
}
```

`Plain value cannot start with block scalar indicator | at line 3, column 20:`

Does anyone know a way to use the fact that yaml is a superset of json to allow this kind of mix and match behavior?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is it yaml you're attempting to imbed into your json or vice versa? Your description makes me think you mean the former. Your code snippet suggests the latter.

Answer (score 2):

YAML has two node styles, *block* and *flow*, with *block* being the one that's usually used:

```yaml
--- # block mapping
foo: bar
droggel: jug

--- # block sequence
- foo
- bar

--- # flow mapping
{ foo: bar, droggel: jug }

--- # flow sequence
[ foo, bar ]

--- # flow scalar
droggeljug

--- # block scalar
|
  droggeljug
```

Block style uses indentation to define structure and nesting, while flow style uses explicit special characters.

Flow style is allowed within block style, making this valid:

```yaml
foo: [droggel, jug]
```

However, block style is not allowed within flow style. I don't know what the reasoning for this decision was but it would make the syntax more complex than it already is, which seems a likely reason.

So the answer to your question is: You can't use a block scalar in a flow mapping. If you want to use a block scalar, are ancestor nodes must also be in block style. You can, however, give sibling nodes in flow style, so this would be valid:

```yaml
name: "John Doe"
description: |
        This is a multi-line
        description using the YAML
        literal style in a JSON file.
other: {
  age: 30,
  }
```

(Hint: the YAML spec requires the closing `}` to be more indented than the enclosing block node. But implementations usually do allow you to put the `}` on the first column. I indented it here for total spec conformance).